# A question on Galois theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory

In this question, the field of rational numbers is  denoted by $\mathbb{Q}$. The Galois group of  a  polynomial $f$ is  denoted by $Gal(f)$. The commutator subgroup of a group $G$ is  denoted by $G'$.

> Is there  a  $\mathbb{Q}$- linear  map  $T$ over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that for all polynomials $f\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$  we have $$Gal(T(f))=(Gal(f))'$$

More  generally we can consider the following situation;

Assume that $T$ is  a  a linear map over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$  and  $\mathcal{F}$ is a functor over the category of groups. we say that $T$ is  Galois-related to $\mathcal{F}$ if we have $$Gal(T(f))=\mathcal{F}(Gal(f))\;\;\;\text{For  all polynomial  } f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$$

What  are some  non trivial examples of such situation?

Comment: I would prefer if the field of rational numbers were not denoted by $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: @guest lollllll!

Comment: I’m not sure what a “$\Bbb Q$-linear map over $\Bbb Q[x]$” might be. Would that be a $\Bbb Q$-linear transformation of this infinite-dimensional $\Bbb Q$-space?

Comment: @guest  thanks for the comment. I revised that.

Comment: @Lubin  Yes  a  linear  map over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$   where $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is  counted  as  a  $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.